# How do i integrate Angular 5 into a symfony 3.4 application

Tags: angular, symfony, symfony-3.4

So far I only installed angular using this command :

> npm install -g @angular/cli

I know the command to make a new Angular project is :

> ng new project

But i want to know how do I integrate it into an existing project in symfony 3.4.

My symfony project is new so i can delete it if there is a workaround.

I hope there's a simple solution since I am a beginner otherwise I may not use a front-end framework if there are other ways to use a different front-end framework such as React or Vue.js

I would like that.

Comment: This question is too broad and off-topic for SO. You should go through [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Finally, if you are sure your question fits the rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a useful, well formed/formatted and on-topic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to integrate Angular with Symfony. You will create a symfony project to develop an API and an Angular project to query your API.

Answer (score 1):

With Symfony you will create an API

and let your angular app isolated and consume the api web services in to your angular app